cannot read property 'convert' of null ERROR in react-native-html-to-pdf how to solve
cannot read property 'convert' of null ERROR in react-native-html-to-pdf how to solve this?
In my react native expo app I try to export array data to a pdf file using the react-native-html-to-pdf module.
My code to export to PDF:
const options = {
        html,
        fileName: `order_${count}`,
        directory: 'Orders',
    
      };
      console.log(options);
      const file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options);
      Alert.alert('Success', `PDF saved to ${file.filePath}`);
      setCount(count + 1);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
    }
  };

When I run my app on iOS the error alert "cannot read property 'convert' of null" is shown.
